# Typescript types: check for correct callback type depending on other argument

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I have a JS function

```js
const fn = (cb, param) => {
  cb(param);
};
```

Which is intended to be called 2 ways (in TS):

```
const cb0 = () => {};
fn(cb0);

const cb1 = (param: string) => { };
fn(cb1, 'str')
```

`fn` expectations are correctly described by this type:

```
interface IFn {
  (cb: (param: string) => void, param: string): void;
  (cb: () => void): void;
}

fnI(cb0); // ok
// fnI(cb1); // correctly does not compile, callback needs an argument
fnI(cb1, 's'); // ok
```

So it checks types at caller sites. However, I can't convert `fn` to Typescript so it would not require a type cast. Moreover, it seems TS refuses to infer argument types since `IFn` declares overloads. The best I can do is:

```
const fn: IFn = <IFn>((cb: (param?: string) => void, param?: string) => {
  cb(param);
});
```

**The problem is** the implementation signature is less restrictive and the following implementation clearly violates assertions of `IFn` but the violation can't be detected by type checker.

```
const fn: IFn = <IFn>((cb: (param?: string) => void, param?: string) => {
  cb(param === undefined ? 'some other string' : undefined);
});
```

**So the question is:** 
Is it possible to define `fn` signature or `IFn` so the above assertions violation inside of the implementation would be found by TypeScript?

Obviously, I'm not interested in runtime checks.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads)? For that matter `const fn: IFn = (cb: any, param?: string) => cb(param);` works fine, the rest of the world only sees it through the `IFn` interface so the `any` doesn't matter.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for the note. I think the interface with overloads in the question is equivalent to function overloads under the link, however in my style I use const + arrow function, so it's not clear how to use function overloads in this case. Also, the question is how can I make use of type checks inside of my function definition, which function overloads do not provide since only the types in the actual definition signature are used.

Comment: It's not clear to me what *problem* you have here. What does *"type checks inside the definition of my function"* mean to you? What do you consider the *"actual definition signature"*? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: @jonrsharpe rewritten the question part

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
interface IFn {
  (cb: (param: string) => void, param: string): void;
  (cb: () => void): void;
}

const fn: IFn = (
  ...args: [(param: string) => void, string] | [() => void]
) => {
  switch (args.length) {
    case 2: {
      const cb = args[0];
      const param = args[1];

      cb(param);
      break;
    }
    case 1: {
      const cb = args[0];

      cb();
      break;
    }
  }
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=25&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDETIN4ChnIAUCARgFxEAOcUcAthQM5hSgDmAlMgLwB8yANwD2wACYAaZNVoNkzViE4VhYgNz4ipCoS59BI0R2UH1AX1y4EQkM2QwKGLNyIaAdO5ptGFANqFp9Ews7Lr8KhJywYoAusgAPsh%20ofpi0bjJeASMAO7AYAgAFkSejK4ANhCKYAVcmQTICHCMKABMFHX1Dda2pDzIJT4ADNHqnQRWNmBSNPR9AwCMIxZjDST%20M3Qco2MkUBBwANbbBOadjc3I8%200aZ91Tvc4Dw%20o39aQ6x-W7%200evp8jmUzqIA)

Comment: I'm only interested in compile-time checks. Transforming the code this way in order to gain type safety is counter-productive.